Unexpected response from SDK
Im using a ios SDK for scanning face in my flutter app using methodChannel and Im getting this error all the time.
flutter: Set Liveness Check status: SUCCESS
setLivenessChecks call args Optional({
    livenessCheck = 100;
})
creted liveness object LivenessCheck(rawValue: 100)
selectedProcess [<EFRSDK.LivenessCheckProcess: 0x303da9130>]
----------------------------------------------------onComplete
{"livenessActionResult":{"elapsedSec":"0","processStatus":"FAILED","livenessAction":""},"faceResult":{"feedbackMessage":"","faceImageHash":"","faceImage":"","processStatus":"FAILED","elapsesTimeSec":"0.0"},"lastWarningMessage":"Initialisation parametter missing"}
----------------------------------------------------
flutter: Set Liveness Check status: SUCCESS

below is my swift code of the method called via channel
if call.method == "setLivenessChecks"{
                    print("setLivenessChecks call args \(String(describing: call.arguments))")
                    if let args: [String:Any]  = call.arguments as? [String:Any]      {
                        if let check:String = args["livenessCheck"] as? String{
                            
                            if let checkCode:Int = Int(check){
                                let liveness:LivenessCheck = LivenessCheck(rawValue: checkCode) ?? .CLOSE_EYES_AND_OPEN
                                print("creted liveness object \(String(describing: liveness))")
                                let selectedProcess:[LivenessCheckProcess] = [LivenessCheckProcess(code: liveness, timeoutSec: 20, checkCycles: 1)]
                                print("selectedProcess \(String(describing: selectedProcess))")
                                do {
                                    try SDK.getInstance.liveness.setlivenessChecks(selectedProcess)
                                    result("SUCCESS")
                                }catch ValidationError.IllegalArgument {
                                        // Show alert: ""
                                    result(FlutterError(code: "1", message: "setlivenessChecksfailed", details: ""))
                                    
                                } catch {
                                    result(FlutterError(code: "1", message: "setlivenessChecksfailed", details: ""))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

Im not familiar with swift btw.
No Exception or error showing in the vscode console while running flutter app. These are the errors Im getting from Xcode
